# Uniqueness of hashcode for Java's HashSet<Double> and its subsets

Tags: java, hashset, hashcode, hash-code-uniqueness

If I have a Java `HashSet<Double>` with a length ranging from 1 to 10.000, are the hash codes of this set and all of its subsets unique?

Comment: A hash code is not ment to be unique, that's the point of a hash code. If your intention ist to distinguish between different objects, re-implement the equals-method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `Object.hashCode()` method implementations (e.g. `HashSet.hashCode()`) are not guaranteed to return a unique value, only a pseudo random value which is good enough for purpose of hash data structures.

If you nee a unique value for `HashSet<Double>` based on the set content you should implement it yourself.

Comment: It is impossible to have a unique hash code for HashSet<Double> because there are more different instances then there are different possible values of hashCode().

Answer (score 1):

The hash code of a set is defined to be the sum of the hash codes of the elements in the set, where the hash code of a `null` element is defined to be `zero`.This ensures that `s1.equals(s2)` implies that `s1.hashCode()==s2.hashCode()` for any two sets `s1` and `s2`, as required by the general contract of `Object.hashCode`.